# How to select 1 row with 2 items from Listbox to use them in method

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to select 1 row with 2 items from listbox to use them in method

here I add 2 items in 1 row

```
Uniqueslist.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} , {1}", MobIDTextUnq.Text, MobCntTextUnq.Text));
```

And I want to use this 2 items in this method

```
public static void Loadmonster(int MobID,int Cont)
{
    DateTime time = System.DateTime.Now;
    time.ToLongTimeString();

    try
    {


        packet.WriteUInt32(MobID); 
        packet.WriteUInt8(Cont); 

    }
}
```

I think it's by loop but I don't know how to do this and I want if this like example 1 row selected never select it again and select the next row and never back again i hope someone help me with this problem .

Comment: Create a plain `MyItem` class containing two `Id`,`Count` properties. Override its `ToString()` method to return `string.Format("{0} , {1}", Id, Count)`. Then when you want to add items to `ListBox` create an instance of that class and set its properties and add it to `ListBox`. Then each item of your `ListBox` would be of that type and shows desired text and for example you can extract those properties `var item = (MyItem)listBox1.SelectedItem;` then `item.Id` and `item.Count` is what you are looking for.

Comment: can you say this with code please to can more understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            var GetItem = UnqEventWindow.Uniqueslist.Items[i];
            var MakeItem = GetItem.ToString().Split(',');

            int MobID = int.Parse(MakeItem[0].Trim());
            int Count = int.Parse(MakeItem[1].Trim());

            myclass.Loadmonster(MobID, Count);
```